# ToggleSwitch in Setting bundle not Working in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

I have one Toggle Switch in my settings bundle, but it is not working for first time. When i changed the value once again in the settings it is working corrctly.

Even i synchronize before using the value:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults synchronize];

if([userDefaults boolForKey:@"KeyName"]) {

    //Do Some Work
}
```

What i have to do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are encountering here is the rather strange issue that the settings in your settings bundle are not loaded until the first time the user runs the settings application.

Straight from Apple:

> For newly installed applications,
>   default preference values from the
>   application’s Settings bundle are not
>   set until the Settings application
>   runs. This means that if the user runs
>   your application before running
>   Settings, the default values specified
>   in your Settings bundle are
>   unavailable.

For more info see: [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: That link is dead and googling it doesnt seem to bring up a new URL for it :(

Comment: Hmmm! Since `[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` is no longer needed I wonder if this is still a problem. How did you run into the issue? (Just not sure if I should try to find an updated link!)

Comment: Reaching out to someone I know at Apple that might be able to help. Will update in the next day or two.

Comment: The Apple person I pinged is not sure if the issue still exists. I can't find the note and don't have a test case handy. Will see if I hear back from @Shayne and update accordingly.

Comment: I haven't thought about this for some time. Link still dead however!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are facing this issue since you haven't registered your default values.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"defaultValueFOrKey", @"Key", nil]];
```

In normal practice, we will create a plist file with the default values for all keys in settings bundle for this purpose and register it as

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];
```